# Remove table column via loop

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 5 columns. I only show one row here:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</TR>
</table>
```

I want to create 5 clone tables, but in each clone I only need to keep one column of the original table.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
</TR>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
</TR>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
</TR>
</table>

etc...
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5- 1; i++ ) {
    $('table:first').clone().insertAfter('table');
    $('table:last tr td:not(:nth-child(i))').remove();
}
```

The problem I have is in this line:

```
$('table:last tr td:not(:nth-child(i))').remove();
```

How do I delete all but this columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate the strings, `i` in your code is a character of a string, it doesn't refer to any variable, it should be:

```
$('table:last tr td:not(:nth-child('+i+'))');
```

Try this:

```
var $tbl = $('table:first');

for ( var i = 0; i < $tbl.find('td').length; i++ ) {
    $tbl.clone()
        .find('td')
        .not(':eq('+i+')')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .end()
        .insertAfter('table:last');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v47GY/

Comment: Uh, I really like this, but I oversimplified my example. I also have TH row http://jsfiddle.net/v47GY/2/

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$('table').after($('table').find('tr:first td').map(function (i) {
     return $(this).closest('table').clone().find('td').not(':nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')').remove().end().end();
}).get());
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63L36/)**

if you have multiple table this would suit the best:

```
$('table').after(function () {
    return $(this).find('tr:first td').map(function (i) { //iterate through td of first tr
        return $(this)
               .closest('table').clone() //get the parent table and clone it
               .find('td').not(':nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')') //select all td that are not in this index
               .remove() //remove all the previously selected tds from cloned table
               .end().end(); //back to the table
    }).get(); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xP6c2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Changing up your html and javascript a little bit to use id's to make selecting easier:

HTML:

```
   <div id="wrapper">
    <table id="my-table">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('#my-table td'),function(index,ele){
        $('#wrapper').append('<table><tr><td>'+$(ele).html()+'</td></tr></table>');
    });
    $('#my-table').remove();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5TT5E/2/

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM? You are generating invalid markup, `html` returns content of an element not it's outerHTML. `tr` element can only have `td` children.

Comment: My apologies for the rush job, i have added the missing td's